# How to solve Exception: basedir doesnot exist

Tags: maven, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to dockerize a springboot project using maven.
So i ran a command

> mvn package -Pdocker  '-Dmaven.test.skip=true' docker:build

Below is the image of how the file structure of the project is
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPbVF.png) and below is the error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:1.0.0:build (default-cli) on project poplar: Exception caught: basedir C:...\server\target does not exist -> [Help 1]

I am trying to find out how i can solve the problem because from the project structure there is no target folder  for the root project poplar  though the subprojects have target folders in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix is to create the `target` directory in the base project directory. For more details about the issue see [here](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin/issues/253). The error is reproduced [here](https://github.com/TomHellier/docker-maven-plugin-Issue253)

I would suggest you change the project structure and add a maven sub-module responsible for building the docker container.